# Im getting an error when I try to run this file. tf learn problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

I found something that i wanted to run from GitHub but when i do i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\GTA\pygta5-master\pygta5-master\Tutorial Codes\Part 14-15\train_model.py", line 4, in <module>
    from alexnet import alexnet
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\GTA\pygta5-master\pygta5-master\Tutorial Codes\Part 14-15\alexnet.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

This is the code

```
# train_model.py

import numpy as np
from alexnet import alexnet
WIDTH = 160
HEIGHT = 120
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 10
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta5-car-fast-{}-{}-{}-epochs-300K-data.model'.format(LR, 'alexnetv2',EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

hm_data = 22
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in range(1,hm_data+1):
        train_data = np.load('training_data-{}-balanced.npy'.format(i))

        train = train_data[:-100]
        test = train_data[-100:]

        X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        Y = [i[1] for i in train]

        test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

        model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=1, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
            snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

        model.save(MODEL_NAME)



# tensorboard --logdir=foo:C:/path/to/log
```

it looks like its trying to get access to the alexnet.py which is

```
# alexnet.py

""" AlexNet.
References:
    - Alex Krizhevsky, Ilya Sutskever & Geoffrey E. Hinton. ImageNet
    Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks. NIPS, 2012.
Links:
    - [AlexNet Paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf)
"""

import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization

def alexnet(width, height, lr):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 3, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=lr, name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_alexnet',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=0, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model
```

After looking around a lot I tried a lot of things and then i tired to import tflearn on a python cmd and it wouldn't import when i ran the command import tflearn. So is it an Tflearn problem?

Im on python 3.6 and here is everything else installed

```
absl-py             0.5.0
astor               0.7.1
gast                0.2.0
grpcio              1.15.0
h5py                2.8.0
Keras-Applications  1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.5
Markdown            3.0.1
numpy               1.15.2
opencv-python       3.4.3.18
pandas              0.23.4
Pillow              5.3.0
pip                 18.0
protobuf            3.6.1
pypiwin32           223
python-dateutil     2.7.3
pytz                2018.5
pywin32             224
setuptools          28.8.0
six                 1.11.0
tensorboard         1.11.0
tensorflow          1.11.0
tensorflow-gpu      1.11.0
termcolor           1.1.0
tflearn             0.3.2
virtualenv          16.0.0
Werkzeug            0.14.1
wheel               0.32.0
```

Comment: This "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." indicates an installation error. In particular, a library that is not installed correctly. You'll have to detail in your question *how* you installed tf and its dependencies: binary download, pip, conda, something else? Your code is likely irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @9769953 i used pip to install it i even uninstalled it and reinstalled it .. but tflearn still seems to be messing up.. thanks for the help

Comment: pip doesn't install binary dependencies (libraries) for you. Using Conda might help, though I'm not fully sure. Or a full blown binary, or even a Docker container.

Comment: Admittedly, I expected that pip would have taken care of the `google.protobuf.pyext` module, but I'm guessing here that there is no pip wheel (binary) for your combination of Python interpreter and OS, and the compilation failed during installation. Do you recall any warnings or errors during installation?

Comment: none that i remember, should i just download it and try to install it using the command line? @9769953